# Making an image appear on screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to instantiate an image programatically, my end aim is to have a series of Empty.png on the screen at different points horizontally. I have no idea how to do that but first of all I'm just trying to make a single image appear on screen. This is my code in the .m file.

```
- (void)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point {
point = CGPointMake(100.0,100.0);
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Empty.png"];
[self.view addSubview:img];
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You are taking an entirely wrong approach.

As a beginner, if you find yourself in drawing code (`drawAtPoint:`, `drawInRect:` etc.), you are almost certainly in the wrong place.

Especially for things like loading and displaying images, iOS does almost all the work for you, so you really don't have to draw anything yourself.

Please do not take this the wrong way, but do yourself a big favor and get a good introductory book on the subject. The books from the Big Nerd Ranch Guide series are excellent, and very well worth the money.

EDIT:

If you really do not want to get a book (please, for your own sake, get a book - I did, and I'm very glad I did), here's a quick way that should work.

You had the right idea in creating a `UIImageView`, but you're using it wrong.

You very probably have a `UIViewController` somewhere in your app. Find (or create) the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method, and display your image from there:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Empty"]; //you can leave out PNG.
    UIImageView *myFirstImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage]; //this automatically gives the UIImageView the correct height and width
    [self.view addSubview:myFirstImageView]; //That's all. UIKit will handle displaying the imageView automatically.
}
```

This will display the image in the upper left hand corner of the screen.

You can easily move it around by inserting the following line somewhere after `UIImageView *myFirst...`:

```
myFirstImageView.center = CGPointMake(210.0, 345.0);
```

Did I mention the Big Nerd Ranch books are great to learn about iOS development, and are also even fun to read?

Also, the official documentation is very good (though not as fun or easy to read, and doesn't explain as much).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my earlier answer was wrong.
I did not realize that you do drawInRect.

Don't use an image view. Here you should stay with core graphics. UIImageView objects may be helpful but just parts of it.

```
[img drawAtPoint:point];
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This is way too low-level stuff, and it will only lead a beginner into a big pile of problems. If you really only want to display an image, a `UIImageView` is the way to go. Just don't do it in `drawRect:` or `drawAtPoint:`. The imageView will handle the drawing for you.

Comment: This is a direct answer to her question. She is in 'drawInSomething' already and has an error and this fixes her error. And frankly, as she went so far already, I do not think that drawAtPoint: is horribly complex stuff. On the contrary. It is rather basic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the frame:

```
- (void)placeImageViewAtPoint:(CGPoint)point 
{
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Empty.png"];
    img.frame.origin = point;
    [self.view addSubview:img];  
}
```

I didn't test this, but if that throws an error you need:

```
- (void)placeImageViewAtPoint:(CGPoint)point 
{
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Empty.png"];
    CGRect frame = img.frame;
    frame.origin = point;
    img.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubview:img];  
}
```

and you should probably call this method from viewDidAppear or a similar method:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear
{
    CGPoint point = point = CGPointMake(100.0,100.0);
    [self placeImageViewAtPoint:point];
}
```